# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Simple ListItems not transitioning when previewing in the console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, listitem, dojox.mobile, worklight-console

I have created a simple project (Hybrid with Dojo) that contains one view with three pages - all created using the Dojo Mobile View wizard.

After I build all and deploy, and preview with the Worklight Console, the view doesn't render the arrows of the list items properly and once a list item is clicked, it looks like the new page opens on top of the view, instead of transitioning.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HelloWorld2App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HelloWorld2App.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view1">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Heading'"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Page 1',moveTo:'page1'"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Page 2',moveTo:'page2'"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Page 3',moveTo:'page3'"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="page1">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Page 1',back:'Back',moveTo:'view1'"></div>On page 1
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="page2">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Page 2',back:'Back',moveTo:'view1'"></div>On page 2
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="page3">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Page 3',back:'Back',moveTo:'view1'"></div>On page 3
    </div>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/HelloWorld2App.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Are you using Worklight Studio on Windows?  32 or 64 bit?  Have you tried opening the console in an outside browser? (like Chrome)  On Windows, Studio has worked best for me when installed as 32 bit and with FireFox configured as the default browser.

Comment: I also don't reproduce. Besides David's hint to check the console for error messages, did you add to the list of required modules all the modules you use in your HTML? Alternatively, and preferably, replace all occurrences of "dojox.mobile." by "dojox/mobile/", which is the modern syntax for markup. When using, say, data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" the module gets automatically loaded even if you didn't require it (see the section "Auto-Require" in http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/declarative/).

Comment: Thank you so much! David, your answer helped me get on the right track. I was using the console in the internal browser and that didn't work. As soon as I changed it to external browser with Firefox, it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Great, then could you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Since Virginie is not copying the answer from the comments, here is answer for all to know:

The above did not work while using the internal browser in Eclipse. After moving to use an external browser this is now working.